# Python - Swap a value for a dictionary item

Tags: python, dictionary

So basically, I have my dictionary, which looks like this:

```
{'my': 2, 'Phil.': 10, 'name': 3, 'Andy.': 5, 'Hello': 1, 'is': 4}
```

and a string that looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 10
```

How can I make it so each number in the string is replaced by the word with the same number in the dictionary? So it would make the sentence:

```
Hello my name is Andy. Hello my name is Phil.
```

I have no idea how to approach this, so help is appreciated.

Comment: *"I have no idea how to approach this"* - then see http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: `str.replace` or `str.format` is your friend. If you tried it and failed please [edit] your question and tell us what you have tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make from your string a list.

```
list_name = string_name.split(' ')
```

Then switch the keys and the values from your dict (if using python 3.x use iter instead of iteritems)

```
my_dict = {y:x for x,y in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

Then you can iter tro your code

```
for numbers in list_name:
    print(my_dict[int(numbers)])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm getting the error line ''list' object is not callable'. How can I fix this?

Comment: Little mistake: the () after list_name need to be removed. I edited the post.

Comment: Now I'm getting 'KeyError: '1''. Any ideas?

Comment: Hopefully my last edit. Sorry I couldn't test it out on my pc.

Comment: Also - iteritems() was removed in python 3. I used items() instead, so that might have something to do with it, although I'm pretty sure they do the same thing.

Comment: And next time you should not add the tag python but python3.X or python2.7